# Background per section

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a background image for the first section and a different one for every other section that is under it, how could I do this?

```css
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}
section:nth-of-type(2n) {
 background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.intro {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>

<section class="intro">  
  
</section>

<section>  
  
</section>

<section>  
  
</section>

<section>  
  
</section>

</body>
```

A code example with placeholder images would be very much appreciated

Comment: use different class for different sections and assign your background property for each class.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.intro{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

section{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

section:nth-child(2){
   width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url('place url here');
}

section:nth-child(3){
   width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url('place url here');
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">  

</section>

<section>  

</section>

<section>  

</section>
```

You can put the url into the different nth child of the sections.